# InternalFrameListener for inter-frame Button pressing?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I need the frame to update and display how many times the Button has been pressed (the button's text to update)
If I can use actionPreformed() to be locked on to specific events (Button press, or the Menu item being pressed), then I think that should help...

Problems:

- When Button is pressed it creates more frames
- The existing Frame(s) do not update (I only want there to be one frame anyway)

  ```
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import javax.swing.event.*;

  public class ButtonFrame implements InternalFrameListener, ActionListener
  {

  JFrame myFrame = null;
  private int clicked;
  final String F=("Clicked: "+clicked+" Times!");

  public static void main(String[] a) 
  {
      (new ButtonFrame()).test();

  }

  private void test() 
  {
      myFrame = new JFrame("Internal Frame with a Button");
      myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      myFrame.setSize(400,400);
      myFrame.setContentPane(new JDesktopPane());
      JMenuBar Start_Bar = new JMenuBar();
      JMenu Start_Menu = new JMenu("Frame");
      JMenuItem Start_Item = new JMenuItem("Start");
      Start_Item.addActionListener(this);
      Start_Menu.add(Start_Item);
      Start_Bar.add(Start_Menu);
      myFrame.setJMenuBar(Start_Bar);
      myFrame.setVisible(true);

  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Start_Item) 
  {
      JInternalFrame f = new JInternalFrame("Button Frame");
      f.setResizable(true);
      f.setClosable(false);
      f.setMaximizable(true);
      f.setIconifiable(true);
      f.setSize(200,200);
      f.setLocation(100,100);
      f.addInternalFrameListener(this);
      f.setVisible(true);

      Button objButton1;
      objButton1=new Button ("Clicked: "+clicked+" Times!");
      objButton1.setBounds(20,90,40,50);
      f.add(objButton1);
      objButton1.addActionListener(this);

      myFrame.getContentPane().add(f);
  }

  public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent objButton1)
  {
      clicked++;
  }

  public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent e) 
  {
      System.out.println("Internal Button Ready");
  }
  public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent e) 
  {
      System.out.println("Internal frame closed");
  }
  public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) 
  {
      System.out.println("Internal frame closing");
  }
  public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent e) 
  {
      System.out.println("Internal frame deactivated");
  }
  public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent e) 
  { 
      System.out.println("Internal frame deiconified");
  }
  public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) 
  {
      System.out.println("Internal frame iconified");
  }
  public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent e) 
  {
      System.out.println("Internal frame opened");
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: objButton1.addActionListener(this); is reusing the ActionListerner that creates new windows. You are also mixing heavy weight (Button) components with lightweight (Swing) components, this is not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you solution is screaming isolation and separation of code responsibility, the code responsible for managing the button should be separated from the code managing the frame and desktop pane

This way, you can use separate `ActionListener`s as well as isolate the functionality to a single instance of the button class

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JDesktopPane dp = new JDesktopPane();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JMenuBar Start_Bar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu Start_Menu = new JMenu("Frame");
                JMenuItem Start_Item = new JMenuItem("Start");
                Start_Item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JInternalFrame f = new JInternalFrame("Button", true, true, true, true);
                        f.setSize(200, 200);
                        f.setLocation(100, 100);
                        f.add(new ButtonPane());
                        f.setVisible(true);
                        dp.add(f);
                    }
                });
                Start_Menu.add(Start_Item);
                Start_Bar.add(Start_Menu);
                frame.setJMenuBar(Start_Bar);

                frame.add(dp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ButtonPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton button;
        private int count = 0;

        public ButtonPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            button = new JButton("0");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    count++;
                    button.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                }
            });
            add(button);
        }

    }

}
```